# activating conda environment in within a shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have an EC2 instance running Ubuntu 18.04. 
I have a python Flask server implemented inside it, and I want it to start running as soon as I boot. I would like to do this with `/etc/rc.local/`.

When I login and run the following in order, the **conda environment activates**, and therefore my Flask server runs well.

```
cd ~
cd pult
conda activate pult
export FLASK_APP=hello.py
flask run
```

So this is what I wrote in `/etc/rc.local`. The file did not exist, so I made one.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~
cd pult
sudo ln -s /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate pult
export FLASK_APP=hello.py
flask run
```

And when I run `/bin/bash /etc/rc.local` I get this error, and the conda environment fails to activate.

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
If your shell is Bash or a Bourne variant, enable conda for the current user with

    $ echo ". /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc

or, for all users, enable conda with

    $ sudo ln -s /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /etc/profile.d/conda.sh

The options above will permanently enable the 'conda' command, but they do NOT
put conda's base (root) environment on PATH.  To do so, run

    $ conda activate

in your terminal, or to put the base environment on PATH permanently, run

    $ echo "conda activate" >> ~/.bashrc

Previous to conda 4.4, the recommended way to activate conda was to modify PATH in
your ~/.bashrc file.  You should manually remove the line that looks like

    export PATH="/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

^^^ The above line should NO LONGER be in your ~/.bashrc file! ^^^
```

I also tried:

- putting `source ~/.bashrc` in line 2 (running this should put `conda` in PATH)
- putting `export PATH="/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"` in place of line 4

But they all give the same error. What should I do, so that `/bin/bash /etc/rc.local` **will activate the conda environment**?

Comment: try using `source /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh` and then do 
`conda activate pult`. lemme know if this doesnt work

Comment: @xxbinxx worked like a charm! Thanks

Comment: I like the quality of your question btw. Very well done. I must say you've gave it a really good try

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try using

`source /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh`

and then do

`conda activate pult`

Cheers!!

Comment: ref to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/572951/282629 could help while using `source` cmd

Answer (score 4):

For reference to future users who want to activate a conda environment in a shell script run on a remote cluster, do this by adding the following line to your shell script:

```
source /home/username/miniconda3/bin/activate myenv
```

instead of `conda activate myenv`.